# closed form for a particular sum of powers of $2$ or approximation

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, summation

> I was wondering if it's possible to find a closed form for the sum $S(n) := \sum_{i=1}^n 2^{2^{i-1}-1}$. I tried using induction but I'm not sure how to find a general formula for the pattern. Clearly $S(1)=1, S(2)= 3, S(3) = 11,$ etc.

> Edit: To clarify, I was wondering if I could find an exact formula for the above sum?

Comment: The sum is asymptotically equivalent to its last term.

Comment: @Maxim okay but can you find an exact formula for the sum? Just finding an asymptotic formula is much easier you know.